# Download all source files for a webpage

Tags: command-line, wget, curl, web

I want to download the source files for a webpage which is a database search engine. Using curl I'm only able to download the main html page. I would also like to download all the javascript files, css files, and php files that are linked to the webpage and mentioned in the main html page. Is this possible to do using curl/wget or some other utility?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you should check with the website operator that this an acceptable use of their service. After that, you can do something like this:

```
wget -pk example.com
```

`-p` gets the requisites to view the page (the Javascript, CSS, etc). `-k` converts the links on the page to those that can be used for local viewing.

From `man wget`:

> *-p, --page-requisites*
>
> This option causes Wget to download all the files that are necessary to properly display a given HTML page. This includes such things as inlined images, sounds, and referenced stylesheets.
>
> [...]
>
> *-k, --convert-links*
>
> After the download is complete, convert the links in the document to make them suitable for local viewing. This affects not only the visible hyperlinks, but any part of the document that links to external content, such as embedded images, links to style sheets, hyperlinks to non-HTML content, etc.

Comment: Would this save all the files in .html .js and .css formats?

Comment: @Venkat The page requisites are retrieved in the same format they are offered in.

Comment: I just have one more question. The page I'm downloading is like a database search engine. Does this command download all the php and mysql scripts that might be associated with the webpage? I can only seem to find css, js and html files. Or are the database queries on a different inaccessible file? Also, the webpage has .php extension if that helps.

Comment: If they're requisites for the page, they will be downloaded. If they're just *linked* to from the page and are not page requisites, then you want `-R` and `-A`, probably.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by requisites?

Comment: I also need to add the recursive flag (`-r`).